# Assigning variable names within a function in R

Tags: r, variables, names

I am currently working on a dataset in R which is assigned to the global enviroment in R by a function of i, due to the nature of my work I am unable to disclose the dataset so let's use an example.

```
DATA
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]   [,5]
[1,] 32320 27442 29275 45921 162306
[2,] 38506 29326 33290 45641 175386
[3,] 42805 30974 33797 47110 198358
[4,] 42107 34690 47224 62893 272305
[5,] 54448 39739 58548 69470 316550
[6,] 53358 48463 63793 79180 372685
```

Where DATA(i) is a function and the above is an output for a certain i

I want to assign variable names based on i such as:-

```
names(i)<-c(a(i),b(i),c(i),d(i),e(i))
```

for argument sake, let's say that the value of names for this specific i is
    c("a","b","c","d","e")

I hope that it will produce the following:-

```
         a     b     c     d      e
[1,] 32320 27442 29275 45921 162306
[2,] 38506 29326 33290 45641 175386
[3,] 42805 30974 33797 47110 198358
[4,] 42107 34690 47224 62893 272305
[5,] 54448 39739 58548 69470 316550
[6,] 53358 48463 63793 79180 372685
```

This is the code I currently use:-

```
VarName<-function(i){
colnames(DATA(i))<<-names(i)
}
```

However this produces an error message when I run it: "Error in colnames(DATA(i)) <- names(i)) : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object" which we can see from my input that isn't true. Is there another way to do this?

Sorry for the basic questions. I'm fairly new to programming.

Comment: Your example is not exactly reproducible, but building on the assumption that you have a matrix, this could be the cause of misunderstanding: `x <- matrix(1:9, ncol = 3);colnames(x) <- letters[1:3];rownames(x) <- LETTERS[1:3];names(x)` which returns `NULL`.

Comment: is DATA() a function? Why not work with the dataframe itself instead of a function?

Comment: I have edited the question to cater for the irreproducibility. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please show what the result would look like for your example

Comment: This doesn't look like a good practice in R, from your VarName function, you'd be best off returning a new data.frame with the names attached, e.g., x = DATA(i); colnames(x) = names(i); return(x)